# json.dumps() problem with non-English characters

Tags: json, python-3.x

I'm trying to serialize a Python dict to JSON format for storing to a database.

```
obj = json.dumps({
    'name':'کوروش'
    }, sort_keys=True, indent=-1, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf-8')
```

but it's not encoded to my native language. I changed the `ensure_ascii` to false but that did not work. What am I doing wrong? I searched in Stack Overflow questions about non-English characters but they all said you must set **ensure_ascii=False**.

Comment: Added ensure_ascii=False. solved my issue but my characters were spanish not Persian

Answer (score 1):

you don't need encode('utf-8') at the end. correct form is as follows:

```
obj = json.dumps({
    'name':'کوروش'
    }, sort_keys=True, indent=-1, ensure_ascii=False)
```

and the output of print will be:

```
{
"name": "کوروش"
}
```